# IDX20803 ERROR : JWT Bearer Token Unable to obtain configuration from 'System.String'

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I used Identity Server 4 for token generation without https protocol , IS4 is working fine giving me the token back , when I try to call authorized method of the another API in Postman by passing the bearer token it shows me this error , but the unauthorized methods are working fine.

I searched for this error but everyone it talking in the context of docker , K8s , OKTA , OWIN , PII is hidden etc. but no has issue related with JWT , please respond if know any correct way how to fix this.

---

My Identity Server is on

> http://localhost:55817

which is working fine.
This link is also working fine

> http://localhost:55817/connect/token

and
this is also working

> http://localhost:55817/.well-known/openid-configuration

---

This is Configure Services authentication method where I have used Identity Server localhost :
**Note** : Please open the link of the image to see the error and settings because I am  not able to indent all the code with 4 spaces Stack Over Flow: Requirement

[image: Configure Services Method]

[image: Exception]

Comment: *I am not able to indent all the code with 4 spaces Stack Over Flow: Requirement* - you just need to add two lines with ```, one before and one after the codeblock. More about [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)) and [why we need it as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please replace these images with the text of the errors, even if you're not sure how to post them as code, as most of us are moderators and can edit them in ourselves. We need the errors as text so we can google the important parts.

Comment: Also, did you mean to tag this with the IDX tag? that's for the real estate industry and might not be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your first image, you're calling your non-ssl endpoint using https.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem for me worked:

##### In root folder of `Identity Server` listening on `http://localhost:55817` run:

```sh
sudo dotnet dev-certs https --clean
sudo dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```